# Apache losing referer information in some cases

Tags: wordpress, apache, plesk-onyx

**Update**

After digging through my Apache access logs I believe the issue is related to hosting, not Google Analytics. Clicking a link to my site sometimes results in the `Referer` information getting dropped.

Here are a few example entries. Some contain a valid referer (Twitter, for example) while others just contain a `-`. For some of these cases, I was tailing the access log while clicking a link from another site so I *know* it should have a valid referer.

```
X.X.X.X - - [10/Jun/2019:03:06:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 12153 "https://twitter.com/PxJVBrEB7T" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
X.X.X.X - - [10/Jun/2019:03:12:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 13535 "https://twitter.com/PTVIpLWqE9" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
X.X.X.X - - [10/Jun/2019:03:50:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 12308 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"
```

This is a Plesk managed hosting account using Apache + Nginx cache. Is it possible Apache is misconfigured and dropping the referer information? Or is more likely something to do with the referring website?

There are multiple referring websites where links aren't showing up properly in the access log, so I suspect it's on the server side but I'm not sure what more to check.

Comment: This should answer your question.. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/what-causes-an-empty-referrer-field-in-a-webserver-log-file

Comment: Thanks. I think some of those probably explain my issue, but I still have a couple links to my site that show up as direct traffic even though I'm clicking from another website.